# Finding the equation of a level curve

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Is there a way in Mathematica to determine a parametric equation of a level curve in Mathematica. For example, consider:

```
f[x_, y_] = (x^2 + 3 y^2) Exp[-x^2 - y^2]; Plot3D[
 f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -2, 0},
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
 Mesh -> {{0.7}}]
```

Any way to find a parametrization of the level curve f[x,y] = 7/10 ?

Comment: Maple produces $$\small \begin{cases} x&={\frac1{t^2+1}\sqrt {-\left(t^2+1\right) {\rm W} \left(-{\frac {7\,t^2+7}{30\,t^2+10}}\right)}}\\ y &= {\frac{t}{t^2+1}\sqrt {- \left(t^2+1 \right) {\rm W} \left(-{\frac {7\,t^2+7}{30\,t^2+10}}\right)}} \end{cases}$$ and $$\small \begin{cases}x&=-{\frac {1}{{t}^{2}+1}\sqrt {- \left( {t}^{2}+1\right) 
{\rm W} \left(-{\frac {7\,{t}^{2}+7}{30\,{t}^{2}+10}}\right)}}\\ y &= -{\frac {t}{{t}^{2}+1}\sqrt {- \left( {t}^{2}+1 \right) {\rm W} \left(-{\frac {7\,{t}^{2}+7}{30\,{t}^{2}+10}}\right)}}\end{cases},$$ where $W$ is the Lambert function.

Comment: Transcendental functions tend to be a bit difficult to parametrize analytically. If need be, you can always build an `InterpolatingFunction[]`.

Comment: The verification shows that the above formulas produce only a part of the level set.

Comment: @user, apart from switching the signs of the square roots, try the "-1" branch of the Lambert function, $W_{-1}(z)$.

Comment: I believe you should de-accept my solution for now. I think that there *is* a way to get a closed-form parameterization by adapting @MarcoB's solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update.** The argument about not getting a nice closed form is of course wrong. (The $W$ Lambert function is nicer than I expected and is implemented in Mathematica as `ProductLog`.) Nonetheless, I think that the numerical solution below is useful, so I will leave this solution up.

**Original post**

As stated by `Guess who it is` in a comment and shown by `user64494`'s functions that are in terms of the transcendental function `W`, you cannot get a nice closed form for the parameterization. A simple way to see this is to note that one way to get the parameterization is to solve `0.7 == f[x, y]` for `y` yielding some function `y[x]`, in which case the parameterization would be `{x, y[x]}`. Unfortunately, the equation

```
0.7 == (x^2 + 3 y^2) Exp[-x^2 - y^2]
```

is a transcendental equation and can't be solved.

So let's take a numerical approach, hinted at by `Guess who it is` in a comment. We first extract the data points from the plot. Using

```
f[x_, y_] = (x^2 + 3 y^2) Exp[-x^2 - y^2];
plot = Plot3D[f[x, y]
  , {x, -1, 1}, {y, -2, 0}
  , MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}
  , Mesh -> {{0.7}}
  , BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

we can extract the curve as a sequence of points using

```
points = Cases[Normal@plot, Line[a_] :> a, Infinity];
```

Using `BoundaryStyle -> None` guarantees that the only `Line` in the plot is the contour of interest. This yields a set of `{x, y}` coordinates for the curve.

We artificially introduce a parameterization variable `t` that takes the value `0` for the first point, `1` for the second point, and so on, so that `t` ranges from `0` to `Length@points - 1`. We create two lists, one for `{t, x[t]}` and one for `{t, y[t]}` via

```
xyLists = Transpose@MapIndexed[{{#2[[1]] - 1, #1[[1]]}, {#2[[1]] - 1, #1[[2]]}} &, points]
```

From these, we create `InterpolatingFunction`s via

```
interps = Interpolation[#][t] & /@ xyLists
```

resulting in a list of two `InterpolatingFunction`s. We create our parameterized function as

```
curve[t_] = Join[interps, {0.7}];
```

Finally, we can plot this:

```
Show[
  Plot3D[
    f[x, y]
    , {x, -1, 1}, {y, -2, 0}
    , Mesh -> None
    , ViewPoint -> {1.5, -1.5, 2.5}
  ]
  , ParametricPlot3D[
     curve[t]
     , {t, 0, Length@points - 1}
    ]
 ]
```

which results in the following plot:

[image]

Comment: I just wanted to point out that `Reduce` will in fact give you explicit solutions for that equation, which is what I used in my answer. Interesting approach nonetheless.

Comment: The first comment demonstrates that the equation is solvable in terms of the Lambert function; it just happens to look messy for this case.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Yeah, apparently I didn't read enough about $W$. Apparently it's the same as `ProductLog` (as shown in MarcoB's solution). I'm going to encourage the OP to unaccept, because I'm pretty sure MarcoB's solution can be adapted for what the OP wants.

Comment: @march Definitely do not delete what you have done. It is awesome and opens a huge window for learning. Great job!

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly a parametrization, but I wonder if this might help:

```
Clear[contourplot]
contourplot[level_] := Module[
  {},
  solns = Reduce[(x^2 + 3 y^2) Exp[-x^2 - y^2] == level, {x, y}, Reals];
  Show[

   Plot3D[(x^2 + 3 y^2) Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None],

   ParametricPlot3D[
    Tooltip[Evaluate[{x, #, level} & /@ (y /. {ToRules[solns[[2]]]})], N@level],
    {x, -1, 1},
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]
   ],

   ImageSize -> Scaled[1/4]
   ]
  ]

Multicolumn[contourplot[#/10] & /@ Range[7, 11], 3, Appearance -> "Horizontal"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I have to warn you, though, that `Reduce` will refuse to collaborate for some level values. I haven't explored numerical solutions because I think they might not be what you are after, but that option may be available as well.

Comment: This is not a parametrization at all.

Comment: @user64494 Yes, well, that's why the post starts with "Not exactly a parametrization, but..." :-)

Comment: @user64494. I believe this can be adapted and turned into a parameterization, however...

Comment: @MarcoB Just a wonderful response. I have so much to learn and this is extremely helpful. I look forward to any updates.